# Write/read recursive structure S4 objects

Tags: json, r, r-s4

I have a recursive structure of `S4` objects , that can be presented ( this is a simple version) by theses 2 classes:

```
cl2 <-
  setClass("cl2",
           representation(
             id = "numeric",
             date="Date"),
             prototype = list(
               date=Sys.Date(),
               id=sample(1:100,1)
             )
  )


cl1 <-
  setClass("cl1",
           representation(
             date="Date",
             cl2 = "cl2"
             ),
           prototype = list(
             date=Sys.Date()
           )

  )
```

I would like to save/load objects of type `cl1`. I opt to use `json` format(suitable for unstructured objects). The problem is with dates. Dates are coerced to numeric? **Is there an option/solution to get dates in the right format when I serialize the object?** Note that the objects can contains other objects ( recursive structure) so I would like that all dates are in the good format.

```
cat(RJSONIO::toJSON(cl1(),pretty=TRUE))
{
    "date" : 16861,
    "cl2" : {
        "id" : 90,
        "date" : 16861
    }
}
```

A solution can be to replace dates by character. But I will loose the validation mechanism of S4 object and I should implement the date validation for all objects. Thanks in advance for any help.

An expected output should be like :

```
{
  "date" :"2016-03-01",
  "cl2" : {
    "id" : 76,
    "date" :  "2016-03-01"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you give an example where it's coerced?

Comment: @MichaelChirico thanks. I added an expected output to the question.

Comment: This structure isn’t actually recursive, it’s simply one class instance nested in another. It would be recursive if (say) `cl1` contained another `cl1`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph good catch. My example is simpler then my real case. But As you can understand the **main question here is about  serializing dates in a well format within nested objects**.

Answer (score 4):

Reading the documentation of `toJSON` I found an interesting parameter:

> `force`    unclass/skip objects of classes with no defined JSON mapping

So I tried and I think this would match you need as you can simply ignore the class entry:

```
> s <- jsonlite::toJSON(cl1(),force=TRUE,auto_unbox=TRUE,pretty=TRUE)
> s
{
  "date": "2016-03-01",
  "cl2": {
    "date": "2016-03-01",
    "id": 67,
    "class": "cl2"
  },
  "class": "cl1"
}
```

Drawback: This is still no loadable "as-is" to s4 objects with `fromJSON` as it will give a named list back, analyzing the list recursively to recreate S4 objects is doable, but you'll have to create the necessary `as` implementation to turn a named list to your classes, for your example:

```
setAs('list', 'cl2', 
      function(from, to) {
        new(to, id=from[['id']], date=as.Date(from[['date']]))
      })

setAs('list','cl1',
      function(from, to) {
        new(to,date=as.Date(from[['date']],cl2=as(from[['cl2']],'cl2')))
      })
```

With a dummy input from previous output:

```
input <- '
{
"date": "2016-03-05",
"cl2": {
  "date": "2016-02-01",
  "id": 83,
  "class": "cl2"
},
"class": "cl1"
}'
```

This gives:

```
> as(fromJSON(input),'cl1')
An object of class "cl1"
Slot "date":
[1] "2016-03-05"

Slot "cl2":
An object of class "cl2"
Slot "id":
[1] 67

Slot "date":
[1] "2016-03-01"
```

I let you adapt this to your real use case, probably using `fromJSON(input,FALSE)` to get a 'pure' list to coerce with `lapply` for example if you have multiples instances of your `cl1` class in the json input.

Comment: Thank you. This is really clever.

Comment: @agstudy FWIW, I can't see any other way, There's probably a way to be clever to define the `setAs` and build the `new` call according to class definition, but defining if it worth the hassle is highly dependent on the complexity of your class. I do think the coercion method is part of the class and should be done along any other method for the class.

Comment: Tensibai  is generallynot an easy subject.  I will wait for @MartinMorgan answer before accepting this one. Just for your information to get a list better, to remove simplification : `fromJSON("fund.json",simplifyVector=FALSE)`

Comment: @agstudy only for simplify=F, this is in the second to last line of my answer :) I did just give this a try as it sounded interesting to find the way back to object.

Comment: As said (at least meant in second comment) I may not take the best approach, I kept it simple according to your example, I may have a better idea on a 'real' or 'as complex as your real' case. I'm pretty sure a generic 'list' to  'cl*' method can be done but this involve a studying the edge cases ...

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the `jsonlite` package to serialize. Indeed `jsonlite::tojson` respects date and serilze them in well formated form. The problem is jsonlite::toJSON is not defined for `S4` objects. My solution is to coerce the object to a list and then seralize it:

```
 ## S4 method to coerce any S4 object to a list
setMethod("as.list",signature(x="ANY"),
          function(x) {
            Map(
                   function(y)  if (isS4(slot(x,y))) as.list(slot(x,y)) else slot(x,y)
            ,slotNames(class(x)))
          })



## coercion
jsonlite::toJSON(as.list(cl1()),pretty=TRUE,auto_unbox=TRUE)
   {
  "date": "2016-03-01",
  "cl2": {
    "id": 24,
    "date": "2016-03-01"
  }
}
```

#### udpdate

in `as.list` I replace `lapply` by `Map` to create a named list.

Comment: If the question is not well defined you ask me and I will add if necessary the omit part. thank you. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

For the recursive reading of S4 classes from JSON you can use a similar approach:

```
library(RJSONIO)
createParser <- function(className) {
  setAs("list", className, function(from, to) {
    to <- new(to)
    for (n in names(from)) {
      if (isS4(slot(to, n))) {
        c <- class(slot(to, n))[[1]]
        o <- as(from[[n]], c)
        slot(to, n) = o
      } else {
        slot(to, n) = from[[n]]
      }
    }
    to
  })
}

Name <- setClass("Name", slots=c("first"="character", "last"="character"))
createParser("Name")
Customer <- setClass("Customer", slots=c("name"="Name", "age"="numeric"))
createParser("Customer")
Case <- setClass("Case", slots=c("customer"="Customer"))
createParser("Case")
c1 <- Case(customer=Customer(name=Name(first="Mika", last="R"), age=100))

j <- RJSONIO::toJSON(c1)
l <- RJSONIO::fromJSON(j, simplify = FALSE)
as(l, "Case")
```